# Replace text with multilines using C# with Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, office-interop

Hope this question finds you will.

I've developed an application called "CreateContract" as the contract is a word template and the main objective of this application is replacing some specific texts that existing into word template with inputs typed via end user with windows form.

Every thing works fine if I replaced text with another text(s) with one line, the issue appears while replacing text with multi-lines via using `RichTextBox` control.

I tried all the next ways without any positive result:-

```
replaceWithText = replaceWithText.ToString().Replace(@"\n", @"\v"); 
replaceWithText = replaceWithText.ToString().Replace("\\n", @"\v");
replaceWithText = replaceWithText.ToString().Replace(@"\n", @"\r");
replaceWithText = replaceWithText.ToString().Replace(@"\n", @"\r\n");
replaceWithText = replaceWithText.ToString().Replace(@"\n", "\u2028");
```

whole code:-

```
static void FindAndReplace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application fileOpen, object findText, object replaceWithText)
{
    //replaceWithText = replaceWithText.ToString().Replace(@"\n", @"\v");
    //replaceWithText = replaceWithText.ToString().Replace("\\n", @"\v");
    //replaceWithText = replaceWithText.ToString().Replace("\\n", @"\r");
    //replaceWithText = replaceWithText.ToString().Replace("\\n", @"\r\n");
    //replaceWithText = replaceWithText.ToString().Replace(@"\n", "\u2028");


    object matchCase = false;
    object matchWholeWord = true;
    object matchWildCards = false;
    object matchSoundsLike = false;
    object matchAllWordForms = false;
    object forward = true;
    object format = false;
    object matchKashida = false;
    object matchDiacritics = false;
    object matchAlefHamza = false;
    object matchControl = false;
    object read_only = false;
    object visible = true;
    object replace = 2;
    object wrap = 1;

    //execute find and replace
    fileOpen.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
        ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
        ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that in the first code block you are using Verbatim string literal's.

You are trying to replace text "\n" with (for example) string "\r\n". But in reality, you want to replace the Newline Control Character (0x0A – often escaped as \n) with some other control characters. When you use the Verbatim String Literals, characters will not be escaped.

For your expected result, remove those "at"(@) symbols from the start of your strings in the first code block.

->  `replaceWithText = replaceWithText.ToString().Replace("\n", "\r\n");` or so on.

Comment: You are right, your notice is the root cause of my issue, many Thanks.